# I have 3 table missing data find in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU955.jpg)

```
select * from TimeSheet
WeekID  StudentID   Hours
1        1           40
2        1           40
4        1           40
1        2           40
2        2           40
3        2           4
4        2           40
1        4           40
3        3           40
```

```
select * from Week
WeekID
1
2
3
4
```

```
select * from Student
StudentID   StudentName
1             ABC
2             XYZ
3             ASD
4             QWE
```

After the join I have these results.

If have this data using three tables

```
select TS.WeekID
     , TS.StudentID
     , TS.[Hours]
     , SS.StudentID
     , WW.WeekID
FROM TimeSheet TS
left JOIN Student SS ON SS.StudentID = TS.StudentID
left JOIN [Week] WW ON WW.WeekID = TS.WeekID
```

```
 WeekID StudentID   Hours   StudentID   WeekID
  1      1          40        1          1
  2      1          40        1          2
  4      1          40        1          4
  1      2          40        2          1
  2      2          40        2          2
  3      2          4         2          3
  4      2          40        2          4
  3      3          40        3          3
  1      4          40        4          1
```

Expectation Result is ...

```
WeekID  StudentID   Hours   StudentID   WeekID

3        1          40          1       2
1        3          40          3       3
2        3          40          3       3
4        3          40          3       3
2        4          40          4       1
3        4          40          4       1
4        4          40          4       1
```

I want to get for example:

- student 1 and week 3 is missing
- student 2 no week is missing
- and student 3 1,2 and 4 week is missing
- and student 4 2,3,4 week is missing.

Please help me out.

Comment: "i want" isn't a question either. What are you asking? What about what you have isn't working?

Comment: SQL And get student 1 missing week 3 and studen 2  no missing week ignor it and student 3 missing week 1,2 and 4 and student 4 missing weeks 2,3,4

Comment: My head got dizzy reading that last sentence

Comment: Plz plz help me out i have already edit the question

Comment: Please , only tag the relevant RDBMS

Comment: Any one plz urgent solved my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cross join your `Week` and `Student` tables to get all combinations, and then use `not exists` to determine where no `TimeSheet` record exists.

```
select W.WeekID, S.StudentID
from [Week] W
cross join Student S
where not exists (select 1 from TimeSheet T where T.StudentID = S.StudentID and T.WeekID = W.WeekID);
```